# How can I exchange the Extjs panel contents?

Tags: extjs

In my application there are two panels -A and B.

I am using "border" layout, the panel A is in center region and panel B is in south region which have height 200.

The "panel A" have lot of items like grid, toolbar etc. also "panel B" have some items.

My question is, How can I exchange the contents of A to B and B to A.

Note: I am using "Extjs 3.2"

Regards,

Mohammed Shafeek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panels in `center` and `south` region of border layout have to be wrapped by container component. Then you can easily get content of each container, clear the container and add to it content from second container.

So function for switch panels should looks like this:

```
function switchPanels() {
    southContainer = Ext.getCmp('southContainer');
    centerContainer = Ext.getCmp('centerContainer');

    southContainerItems = southContainer.items.getRange();
    centerContainerItems = centerContainer.items.getRange();

    southContainer.removeAll(false);
    centerContainer.removeAll(false);

    for (var i = 0; i < southContainerItems.length; i++) {
        centerContainer.add(southContainerItems[i]);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < centerContainerItems.length; i++) {
        southContainer.add(centerContainerItems[i]);
    };  

    centerContainer.doLayout();
    southContainer.doLayout();
}
```

For complete live example look at this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2iv

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks a lot friend, Its really helpful to me... Now My application is showing magics. :)